# Managing Symfony BadCredentialsException codes

Tags: symfony

I have a login form in my symfony project (I'm a brand noob in symfony), and I want to react differently depending on the error I get.

I read the documentation of [BadCredentialsException](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Exception/BadCredentialsException.html) and its parent class [AuthenticationException](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Exception/AuthenticationException.html), but didn't find anything about the code of the error, which I get whenever I dump `getLastAuthenticationError()` with Twig :

```
BadCredentialsException {#93 ▼
  -token: UsernamePasswordToken {#92 ▶}
  #message: "Bad credentials."
  #code: 0
  #file: "C:\pathToProject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\UserAuthenticationProvider.php ◀"
  #line: 90
  -trace: {▶}
}
```

So far I always have the 0 code.

Is there any other codes ? Where can I find them in the doc ?

Also, this exception seems to happen whether the password is bad or the user does not exist. Is there any way to differentiate these 2 events ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no codes I'm aware of associated with `Exception` in the `Symfony/Security` component. Note that is not (yet?) a common practice to set up code within an Exception. You rather check the type of `Exception` using `TypeHinting` in the `catch(Exception $e)` statement. Or by using the `instanceof` operator.

The `BadCredentialsException` is thrown if the credentials are invalid AND if the User is not found. However, you can reconfigure the `UserAuthenticationProvider` to do not "hide" it.

Check [`UserAuthenticationProvider.php`](https://github.com/symfony/security-core/blob/master/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php), there is an option in the constructor.

You can set it up in your `security.yml`:

```
security:
   hide_user_not_found: false
```

Depending on your use case, you may also want to write your own implementation of the `AuthenticationProviderInterface`.

Comment: I think you missed the "noob" part of my question^^

Comment: Still, the UserAuthenticationProvider.php constructor option seems very interesting, but I dont have a clue about how to use it, since symfony throw the exception without asking for me.

Comment: @DanChaltiel, the option is basically what you want. If you check  [UserAuthenticationProvider.php#L72](https://github.com/symfony/security-core/blob/master/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php#L72), I gave in my answer, you can see the method is checking for this option to either throw a `UsernameNotFoundException` or `BadCredentialsException`. It is not about being a n00b, it is about taking time to check the source ;)

Comment: @DanChaltiel, I edited my answer with the correct configuration to set. I got it running `php bin/console debug:config security`

Comment: You rock !! Except it is `hide_user_not_found: false`. I saw the line 72, but beeing a noob prevented me to link the code to the hide_user_not_found parameter. Thanks a lot !

Comment: And I come to see that the difference between a bad password and a not found user is the exception thrown, not the code of the exception.