# Override BadCredentialsException on login fail with symfony and FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.8

I am using Symfony 2.8 with FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle 2.12 version.

**I am expecting a specific login error message** like if I input the wrong username then I should get the error message "username not found" and if I give the wrong password then I should get the error message "password is not valid" something like that.

but instead, I am getting the same error message "Bad credentials" on those above conditions.

after further researching, I found that Symfony is hiding UsernameNotFoundException in the UserAuthenticationProvider.php file in authenticate method:

```
    try {
        $user = $this->retrieveUser($username, $token);
    } catch (UsernameNotFoundException $e) {
        if ($this->hideUserNotFoundExceptions) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException('Bad credentials.', 0, $e);
        }
        $e->setUsername($username);

        throw $e;
    }
```

I Dump error object in the login form. here is a screenshot: [image]:

Anyone has an idea of how can I get a specific error message. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the [security config reference](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html).  There is an option to reveal the username not found exception.  You normally want it hidden to make it a bit more difficult for someone to randomly hack the account.

Comment: i tried this option https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/configuration/security.html#user-checkers
but didn't help me? could you please tell me which option exactly. thanks

Comment: hide_user_not_found:  false

Comment: thanks, now it's working, you may add this as an answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304091/managing-symfony-badcredentialsexception-codes/41304202#41304202

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set it up in your security.yml:

```
security:
   hide_user_not_found: false
```

Please see this answer for more details: [Managing Symfony BadCredentialsException codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304091/managing-symfony-badcredentialsexception-codes/41304202#41304202)